# Signed equivalent of Integer.toBinaryString method?

Tags: java, integer

I am using Integer.toBinaryString to convert floats to intbits (Float.floatToIntBits()) into binary. However, the result is unsigned. Is there a way I can get a signed base two result? I am not looking for a two's compliment representation.

I also want to do the reverse, turned a signed binary number to float.

Answer (score 1):

If `value` is the `int` that you want to convert, you could do something like

```
value < 0 ? 
    ( "-" + Integer.valueOf(-value).toBinaryString()) :
    Integer.valueOf(value).toBinaryString();
```

I don't want to answer your second question here - you added it after I posted this.

Comment: This doesn't correctly do twos complement for negative values. Perhaps this is fine for the OPs question, but that needs to be clarified.

Comment: @acomar The OP specifically asked NOT to have twos complement.  He/she wanted negative numbers to come out with a sign.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misunderstood what the OP meant by "signed base two result".